# Google bot indexing.many |GET| requests

Tags: indexing, bots

is it normal that http://www.google.com/bot.html
is doing 12K sometimes 20K of |GET| request on my site every 10 minustes?

Comment: Are you sure it's an actual GoogleBot? It'd be easy to fake the GoogleBot user-agent and other information. Have you double-checked the IP it's coming from?

Comment: Actually im using external WAF so the source ip coming from him.il download the waf incoming ips logs and lookup.but is it a "normal" numbers?

Comment: From the last 2000 req log i see that the ip coming from google servers.were talking about 2.5K request per min.